# How to Speech.Remove everything but a key word

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I know how to

```
if(speech.Contains("this"))
query = speech.replace("this", "");
```

But how do I replace everything but one word.... for instance.

if the speech contains "what" "are" I want it to do a IF statement... but if I say "Can you tell me what are dogs"

and I do speech replace, yes it will remove those but it still makes my speech contain everything else I said.

Example*

```
if(speech.Contains("What") || (speech.Contains("are")))
{

 query = speech.Replace("what are", "");

}
```

but how do I get rid of everything else I might say like "Can you tell me" but still keeping the last word I said in my speech which is "dogs"

Comment: You need to supply a more general case, at the moment your question reads as "how do i replace a string that contains the words dogs, with just the word dogs". Which you can do with `var someString = "dogs";`

Comment: You dont need the `if` check, since replace will return the original string if the word is not found `If oldValue is not found in the current instance, the method returns the current instance unchanged. `

Comment: I think you need to rename your title to something like `Replace everything in String except specific word`.

Comment: if you just want the last word then split the string on spaces and get the last element of the array - to many of you are focused on what the title is, if so just move on instead of posting comments bashing the title, you are all smart enough to understand the question after the first edit of the title.

Comment: Thank you Sorceri!! I dont get why everyone is being so weird about the title. I had a little trouble explaining it but no need to mark my post down because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using just a white list:

```
string[] allowedWords = { "what", "are", "dogs" };

var speech = "Can you tell me what are dogs?";

var words = speech.split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var cleanSpeech = "";

Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");

foreach(var word in words)
{
    var cleanWord = rgx.Replace(word , "").ToLower();

    if(allowedWords.Contains(cleanWord))
       cleanSpeech += word + " ";
}

cleanSpeech.Trim();
```

Define all your acceptable words in lowercase as the function does a ToLower() to avoid casing problems, it also takes care of punctuation (dots, exclamations, commas, questions, etc).